# Issue with parsing html with lxml by xpath

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, lxml, lxml.html

I am trying to parse data from a google interactive website.  It is rendered in JS, so I use Qt to load the site to parse from.  I believe I have the site loaded and rendered properly, but for some reason I am getting and empty list returned to me when I execute the xpath parsing code.

Here is my full code:

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  
from lxml import html 

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit() 

url = 'https://www.consumerbarometer.com/en/graph-builder/?question=M1&filter=country:singapore,canada,mexico,brazil,argentina,united_states,bulgaria,austria,belgium,croatia,czech_republic,denmark,estonia,finland,france,germany,greece,hungary,italy,ireland,latvia,lithuania,norway,netherlands,poland,portugal,russia,romania,serbia,slovakia,spain,slovenia,sweden,switzerland,ukraine,united_kingdom,australia,china,israel,hong_kong_sar,japan,korea,new_zealand,malaysia,taiwan,turkey,vietnam'  
#This does the magic.Loads everything
r = Render(url)  
#result is a QString.
result = r.frame.toHtml()

#QString should be converted to string before processed by lxml
formatted_result = str(result.toAscii())

#Next build lxml tree from formatted_result
tree = html.fromstring(formatted_result)

archive_links = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main-page-wrapper"]/div/section/div/section[1]/div/div/graph/div/div[4]/div/div/graph-bar-chart/div[2]/svg/g[1]/g[2]/g[1]/text()')
print archive_links
```

This is the html that I am trying to grab:
`<text class="bar-text-label" y="22" dy="10">Argentina</text>`

Any thoughts why I am getting `[]` returned to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a shorter and more reliable xpath expression and you have to use namespaces:

```
tree.xpath('//text[@class="bar-text-label"]/text()', namespaces={'n': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'})
```

---

Alternative solution could be to use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) browser automation package:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.consumerbarometer.com/en/graph-builder/?question=M1&filter=country:singapore,canada,mexico,brazil,argentina,united_states,bulgaria,austria,belgium,croatia,czech_republic,denmark,estonia,finland,france,germany,greece,hungary,italy,ireland,latvia,lithuania,norway,netherlands,poland,portugal,russia,romania,serbia,slovakia,spain,slovenia,sweden,switzerland,ukraine,united_kingdom,australia,china,israel,hong_kong_sar,japan,korea,new_zealand,malaysia,taiwan,turkey,vietnam')

// wait for svg to appear
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'svg')))

for text in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('bar-text-label'):
    print(text.text)

driver.close()
```

Comment: I had actually just tried the shorter xpath expression above and even with the namespace addition, I am still getting an empty list returned.

Comment: @Meepl hm, I haven't tried using `pyqt4`, but I've saved the page source in to an html file, parsed it with `lxml.html` and used the provided xpath - worked for me. Anyway, would you be okay with an alternative "selenium" based solution? Thanks.

Comment: yes, absolutely.  i have selenium installed, but i am quite unfamiliar with it

Comment: this worked perfectly! thank you, so now my issue is that I am attempting to get the data value for each country, which has the element type :`<rect rx="3" ry="3" width="76%" height="40" transform="translate(0,40)" data-value="76" class="bar"></rect>`  is it possible to grab the `data-value` attribute with selenium?  I tried `for text in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('bar'):
    print(data_value.text)` but it did not work.

Comment: I also tried this, which did not work: `for data in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@data-value)]/@data-value'):
    print(data.text)`

Comment: @Meepl sorry, was AFK, as far as I understand, you've solved the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @alexce don't worry about it! yes, the problem has been solved.  thanks for your help!!